# How to make kafka connect to pick up messages from last failure

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Elastic search Kafka connect in stand alone mode .
I am not confused in which configuration to use  in order to start Kafka connect and pick up from the last failure point .

For example producer will keep on pushing records into Kafka and Consumer as Elastic Search  sink connector is consuming ,Now my for some reason my consumer is down but still my prouder will keep on pushing messages into Kafka .
Now when i have fixed my issue in ES sink connector side and if i restart ES sink connector it should pick from last failure not from beginning or latest but from last failure .
If 10 messages has come since failure then when ES sink connector starts it should first sink 10 and then latest .

Please help with configuration .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect acts as any other Kafka Consumer. When you restart, the consumer will rewind back to the last committed offset position. This is the default behavior, and there are no settings to change it within Connect.